# show $|J(x)| \leq K |x|$ for a linear map $J$

Tags: real-analysis

let $J: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be linear. Show that $|J(x)| \leq K|x|$ for some $K$.

My attempt:

Let $\{f_i \}_i$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$$J(x) = \sum_i^n x_i f_i$$ for some scalar $x_i$

so $$|J(x)| = |\sum_i^n x_i f_i| \leq \sum_i |x_i f_i| = \sum_i |x_i| |f_i| \leq \text{max}_i |f_i| \sum_i^n |x_i| = K |x|$$ where $K = \text{max}_i |f_i|$. Are all of these steps valid? I worry as I have not used the fact that $J$ is linear.

Comment: I think the problem statement needs to be cleaned up. What space does $K$ live in? Is it just a constant? Also, I'm assuming that $|\cdot |$ is a norm? If this is the case, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator

Comment: You use the fact that $J$ is linear when you write $J(x) = \sum_i x_i f_i$. But I think there is some confusion in your argument. The $f_i$ are not just any vectors: in fact they define $J$. If you fix bases of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, the $f_i$ are the columns of the matrix for $J$. Also, the $f_i$ need not be a basis. Given that $f_i$ depend on $J$ and not on $x$, your argument is valid.

Comment: @MichaelJarret yes $K$ is just a number, and $|.|$ is a norm also. The link you provided is indeed the same problem, do you know where I could find a proof?

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret could you elaborate why $f_i$ need not be a basis, and what you mean that $f_i$ depend on $J$ and not on $x$. As it stands, I meant that $f_i$ only depend on the space $\mathbb{R^n}$, and the $x_i$ are just numbers

Comment: I was assuming you meant $x_i$ to be the $i$th component of $x$ with respect to some basis as that is what is typically meant by $x_i$. In that case the $f_i$ are vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that define $J$. But maybe you could clarify what you really mean. $J(x)$ depends on $x$ so the $x_i$ must depend on $x$ - how?

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret what you wrote is exactly what i mean. $x = (x_1,...,x_n)$. since $x \in \mathbb{R^m}$, perhaps I should have wrote $x = (x_1,...,x_m)$ but then I am not sure how to express $J(x)$.. I see what you mean. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Okay. Then $f_i$ are the columns of the matrix for $J$. In other words, $J$ defines $f_i$ or equivalently, $f_i$ determine $J$. So $f_i$ depend on $J$ but not on the choice of $x$. Also, if the rank of $J$ is less than $m$ then the $f_i$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret thanks, I think I got it now, with help with the below answer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the standard basis $e_1,\ldots,e_m$. Let $y \in \mathbb R^m$, and let $\hat{y} = \frac{y}{|y|}$ be the associated unit vector. Suppose $\hat{y} = c_1e_1 + \cdots + c_ne_n$, so that $|c_i| \leq 1$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$. Then
$$\frac{1}{|y|} |Jy| = \left|J\frac{y}{|y|}\right| = |J\hat{y}| = \left|\sum c_iJe_i\right| \leq \sum |c_i Je_i| \leq \sum |Je_i| = K < \infty.$$
Since $K$ is independent of $y$, multiplying through by $|y|$ gives the desired result.